# Backbone Jquery show() not animating on second load

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

My problem is I load the page the first time and the view comes up correctly.  The show function does its animation but when I navigate to a different view and come back, it doesn't animate but still shows.  In the router I create a new view for each page navigated to.

I am saving the collection to a global called app as to limit loading.  The show animation works when i recreate the collection each time which makes me think its something in the render method.  I think it may have something to do with the fact that jquery has cached the old element and when I add the template to the page again, the selector is looking for the old element not the new one.

My code for the page view is as follow.  Like i said it works correctly the first time but then the second time the animation does not happen.

```
    initialize: function() {
    if(!app.collections.boardsList)
        app.collections.boardsList = new app.BoardsListCollection();

    this.listenTo(app.collections.boardsList, "add", this.renderOne);
    this.listenTo(app.collections.boardsList, "reset", this.render);
    this.listenTo(app.collections.boardsList, "change", this.render);

    this.render();

    app.collections.boardsList.fetch();
    this.interval = setInterval(function(){
        app.collections.boardsList.fetch();
        console.log("Fetching");
    }, 10000);

},

render : function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    this.renderAll();
    return this;
},

renderAll : function(){
    app.collections.boardsList.each(this.renderOne, this);
},

renderOne : function(item){
    var container = !this.state ? "#left-list" : "#right-list";
    var boardView = new app.BoardsItemView({
        model : item
    });
    boardView.$el.hide();
    boardView.render();
    this.$el.find(container).append(boardView.$el);
    boardView.$el.show("fast");
    this.state = this.state ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
There is a incompatibility when backbone try to catch the jquery object.
I resolved it using directly select's jquery